# Octave 5.1.0 -Symbolic package installation error

Tags: python, gnu, octave

I just installed Octave 5.1.0 and need to use the symbolic and control packages with it on my Windows 10 machine.
When I first opened the application, I tried this to install Symbolic:

```
>>pkg install -forge symbolic
```

I got this message and I need help understanding what's wrong and how to solve it:

```
system: unable to start subprocess for '"tar xf "/C/Users/username/symbolic-2.8.0.tar.gz" 2>&1"'

error: called from

  unpack at line 265 column 22
  untar at line 48 column 5
  install at line 81 column 9
  pkg at line 441 column 9
```

I have Python 3.7.4 installed along with sympy.
I have added Octave to the system variable PATH.
I made sure My folder path in octave is the same.
I even tried manually downloading a Symbolic package tar.gz file into the folder but nothing worked.
I finally even tried reinstalling Octave and rebooting my PC. Nothing worked.
I couldn't find a solution anywhere else.

Comment: Do you have the _Tape ARchiver_ (`tar`) Software Utility installed on your Machine, @Dhanush?

Comment: I did not have  `tar` on my machine. Like the 1st answer I received suggested I did install and add it to path but with no effect. I'm getting the same error. Is there any other solution to this?

Comment: What can we say, @Dhanush? You have specified that "_I tried the whole process exactly the same way from the beginning on a different_ Windows **10** _machine and it worked perfectly fine!_" For the latest more than four years, the _MicroSoft_ _Windows_ **10** Operating System has been behaving so strangely that it is difficult to track its numerous versions and settings that might impact it. Most people are encouraging the Clean ReInstallation Procedures. When everything else is failing, that is the direction to take. It is useless to waste time into Endless Debugging.

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai I've just resolved to using the other PC for now. I guess it is a waste of time to keep retrying and debugging when I could be working during all that time. Thank you for your time though.

Comment: It is all right, @Dhanush. We have been playing forward and backward once with one hundred and seven replies trying to solve [a similar issue](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/failure-while-installing-the-microsoft-windows/47e9bd09-def5-47b1-8ae9-b6fad1b9c68c). Maybe there _is_ a hidden cause somewhere, but it seems to be increasingly difficult to find it. Also, sometimes the issue seems even difficult to be described. Sometimes, there seems to be nothing wrong anywhere with anything. This is our _MicroSoft_ _Windows_ **10** Operating System these days.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments, you are likely lacking [tar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)) on your Windows system. This is understandable since `tar` is traditionally a *nix utility. Python is trying to invoke `tar` via the Python [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module (which executes non-Python commands) to extract your `.tar.gz` file and seems to be failing.

One remedy for this might be to install a Windows version of tar ([such as the one made available by the GNUWin32 project](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gtar.htm)).

Note that for the `tar` command to work, `tar` will probably need to be manually added to your Windows Path as well, so it can be executed from the command line (you may need to reboot your PC for this).

Comment: I installed the windows version of `tar` and i did manually add it to PATH and rebooted. I opened GNU Octave to run the pkg install command and I end up with the exact same error. Please let me know if you need any more specific information about the process I followed.

Comment: Is there any other solution? I tried the whole process exactly the same way from the beginning on a different windows 10 machine and it worked perfectly fine! I guess this shows it's something specific to that Windows system. I hope this might help guess what the problem might be?

Comment: Does the other machine have a different username perhaps? Spaces and non-standard (e.g. unicode) symbols can potentially interfere with Python.

Comment: No unusual symbols or characters. Just alphabets.